# Coefficient of expansion discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the coefficient of $x^{12}y^{12}$ in the expansion of $(3x-7y)^{24}$?
I am just checking if I answered it in the correct way. Since its the expansion  to the power of 24 and $(xy)^{12} = (x^{12})(y^{12})$ then i Just substituted $3x$ and $-7y$ with x and y. I got $(3x)^{12}(-7y)^{12}\binom{24}{12}$. Is my reasoning correct or is there much more to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use binomial theorem and you have:

$$(x+y)^k = \sum_{n=0}^k \binom{k}{n} x^ny^{k-n}$$

Now just substitute $x = 3x$, $y=-7y$ and $k=24$. To check the coefficient in front of $x^{12}y^{12}$ additionaly substitute $n=12$

Actually that's what you have done, but you were working solely on you intuition, but I think it's good way to know there's general formula for this.

Comment: Thank you, very clear and concise.